# Are there identities for $x^n+y^n=1$ for all odd exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I see the following identity in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259013/can-we-use-the-rogers-ramanujan-cfrac-to-parameterize-the-fermat-quintic-x5y

$\left(\frac{x^3y + y}{x y^3 + x}\right)^3+\left(\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x y^3 + x}\right)^3=1,\quad \text{if}\; x^3+y^3=1$

Is there a general way to find these identities for other odd prime exponents?